# SAS let statement: refer to a cell value?

Tags: sas, let

In SAS, is it possible to refer a `%let` statement to a value located in a database?

For instance, the value of my n in `%let n=50` depends on some value calculated in one of my databases, e.g., first row plus first column. And since that value gets modified 100 times in my loop I don't want to manually enter that value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's several ways to do this. Here's two:

```
proc sql;
 select a+b into :n
 from your_table
 where some_condition;
quit;
```

This populations a macro variable, `&n`, with the sum of the variables `a` and `b`. The condition you specify should be true only for one row of your table.

Another approach:

```
data tmp;
 set your_table;
 if _n_=1 then do;
  call symputn('n',a+b);
 end;
run;
```

Comment: Ah perfect! I did some additional reading on the command symputn and symput. In fact I used symput and not symputn - SAS kept on giving me an error message while using symputn. Anyhow, everything works! thanks again.