# SAS %let statement to equal a called upon value from a table?

Tags: sas

Is it possible to assign a `%let` statement to equal a called upon value from a table? I know I can do this in a loop with the following code.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select NameID into :Name separated by " "
    from Registration;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
    select count (*) into :NumNAME
    from Registration;
quit;
```

Is there a way to do it outside of a loop, or in only one step, by creating some `%let Name =` to something to just directly call upon a table?  I realize this is similar to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089896/sas-let-statement-refer-to-a-cell-value), I'm just more picky.

Comment: What you are asking/saying doesn't really make any sense.  There isn't a loop here, except that you'd need to USE a loop to access the data there.  What are you actually trying to do?  The specific thing you're describing isn't a very good idea anyway, so perhaps the ultimate result would be helpful to know.

Comment: I created a table to find a number attached to a name. I want to set the number found as a variable without having to manually set it as that number. I didn't know if there was a way to set the let statement to go into the table and use that number without me having to either type the number as that variable or if the let statement could search a table.

Comment: That's not what I wanted to know.  What are you trying to do overall?  You should not typically use variables in the way it sounds like you are trying to - SAS is not a programming language with global variables or anything like that, data should be stored in datasets, not macro variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%Let statements aren't very flexible for this sort of thing.

[CALL SYMPUT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000210266.htm), however, can be used in the middle of datasteps to set macro variables and would probably help more.

How About:

```
data myReg;
INPUT Name $;
DATALINES;
Alex
Alex
Ben
Ben
Ben
Calvin
Calvin
Calvin
Calvin
;
run;

proc sort data=myReg; by name;run;
data MakeSomeMacroVars;
        set myReg end=LastRow;
        by name;

        length Allnames $30000;*Variable for space separated list of names;
        retain AllNames ' ';

        cnt+1;
        if last.name THEN DO;
                *Create a macro variable NUM_Alex or similar, with value equal to cnt;
                CALL SYMPUT (cats('NUM_',name),cats((put(cnt,12.))));
                cnt=0;
                *Add name to space separated list;
                Allnames = catx(" ",AllNames, name);
        END;

        if LastRow THen do;
                Call Symput ('AllNames',cats(compbl(AllNames)));
        END;
RUN;
%Put Alex has --&NUM_Alex--; * --> 2;
%Put Ben has --&NUM_Ben--; * --> 3;
%Put List of names is: --&AllNames--; * --> Alex Ben Calvin;
```

Comment: I guess this is the closest thing to what I'm looking for. I think it's a little more complicated than I was hoping but knowing that it COULD be done is good enough!

Comment: Cool - I'd still recommend thinking a bit about Joe's comments above to resolve the COULD/SHOULD question for your particular case.  Its always best to write code that appeals to the language's strengths.  For SAS, handling variables is fairly primitive compared to most full fledged programming languages, IMO.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it's also useful to note that `select into:` is the `proc sql` equivalent of `call symput()`.